# Unable to click the button in SAP table using UFT one

Tags: automated-testing

Am automating SAP, now there is a button inside SAP table I have been trying to click it my code is failing.

object:

```
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("SAP").SAPGuiTable("SAP User Selection").ClickCell
```

[image]

I want to click the button "300". please see the attached image

Comment: How are you referencing the cell you wish to click?